# Excel Conditional Formatting Issue

Tags: excel

I have set up conditional formatting to highlight the differences between two log tables.  Rule 3 works, as shown by the green highlighted cells.  Rules 1 and 2 fail.   What is going on here?
[image]

Comment: I suspect that conditional formatting rules have hidden content that is not visible in the conditional formatting editor.  And I further believe that Bill Gates owes us an apology for the outrageous behavior of that editor when the left and right arrow keys are used to move the cursor.

Comment: @richard1941 L O L S O T R U E

Comment: @richard1941, you can tap F2 to enter Edit Mode (see lower left status bar for confirmation) just as you can when editing a worksheet formula in the formula bar or a named range definition.

Comment: Conditional formatting rules are like nested IF statements. You may need to order them correctly so one does not supersede another. Move the green rule to the top to see if that makes a partial if not full correction. If not, you may have to add some AND NOT clauses to the super-secret formulas that make up the rules.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, isn't the *Stop if true* solely for backwards compatibility to xl2003? I thought it was a placebo in xl2007+.

Comment: @user11053804 A little testing reveals that the order of the various statements is critical, as you indicate.  Not being able to see the OP's formulas led me to suggest *Stop if True*. I'll remove that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got the subject sheet formatted as intended by means of an illogical hack.  I created a third spreadsheet that referenced the two that were to be compared.   There all of the formatting worked.  I then copied that entire sheet and did a special paste of format only onto the subject sheet.   It makes no sense why this would work, but at least I got what I was after: a log table that is better than the traditional table showing the increases and decreases in the tabulated values.  user11053804, thanks for the F2 tip!